# How is $M(S,G)$ a group where it's the set of all functions $f:S\rightarrow G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem:

Let G be a group (written additively), $S$ a nonempty set, and $M(S,G)$ the set of all function $f:S\rightarrow G$. Define addition in $M(S,G)$ as follows: $(f+g):S\rightarrow G$ is given by $s\mapsto f(s)+g(s)\in G$. Prove that $M(S,G)$ is a group.

$M(S,G)$ must be a semigroup first. For that, 

$\forall s\in M(S,G); \Big( (f+g)+h\Big)(s)=(f+g)(s)+h(s)=\big(f(s)+g(s)\big) +h(s)\stackrel{*}{=}f(s)+\Big(g(s)+h(s)\Big)=f(s)+\Big((g+h)(s)\Big)=\Big(f+(g+h)\Big)(s)$ 

$*$: $G$ is a group.

How is it a monoid and how do its elements have inverses?

Comment: What is the neutral element? The map that maps all $s\in S$ to the neutral element of $G$, call this map $0_M$. What is the inverse of $f$? Is a function $g$ such that $\forall s\in S$ we have $(f+g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)=0_M(s)=0_G$, so in particular you can "build" $g$ as $\forall s\in S, g(s)=-(f(s))$

Comment: I pressed "Enter" to fast before, I corrected the comment ;)

Comment: @dadexix86 And there's the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'll write it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the *neutral element*?
It is the map that maps all $s\in S$ to the neutral element of $G$, call this map $0_M$.

What is the *inverse* of $f\in M$?
It is a function $g$ such that $\forall s\in S$ we have
$$(f+g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)=0_M(s)=0_G,$$
so in particular you can "build" $g$ as $$\forall s\in S,\quad g(s)=-(f(s))$$ and define the inverse $$\forall f\in M, \forall s\in S, \quad (-f)(s)=-(f(s)).$$

Comment: Could you be more specific on saying this for the neutral elements? What can it be in the form of
$\forall f\in M, \forall s\in S, \exists g\in M; (f+g)(s)=(g+f)(s)=f(s)$

Comment: I guess it's like $(f+0_M)(s)=(0_M+f)(s)=f(s)+0_M(s)=f(s)$, right?

Comment: Can I use a notation such as: $0_M:S\rightarrow 0_G$, where $0_G$ is the neutral element of $G$.

Comment: Yes, I would use the last notation.